# Oracle 11G Can't create database from template

Tags: oracle-11g

I am attempting to create a new database from an existing template in Oracle 11G.
I have done this before using dbca and haven't had a problem, but now I am hitting the following error:

```
TNS-04404: no error caused by oracle.net.ConfigException: 
TNS-04414: File error caused by: 
TNS-04610: No literals left, reached end of NV pair
```

After some research I found out that the TNS-04610 is likely a problem with the tnsnames.ora file. I found this file in the $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/ directory. The files contains the following:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_3/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.




BASE_901_NEW =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = BASE_901_new)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.domain.com)
    )
  )

BASE_901 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = Base_901)
    )
  )

TEST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = Test)
    )
med =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = med)
    )
```

As far as I can tell that file looks correct.  Is there a syntax error that I'm not aware of?
This file was not created by me, and as far as I know it has not been manually edited by anyone.

Any leads are appreciated as I have not been able to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two entries have unbalanced parenthesis. You're not closing the top-level parens.

```
TEST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = Test)
    )
  )              -- add this
med =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = med)
    )
  )              -- add this
```

(Don't add the comments though.)

Might be a good idea to be consistent with casing everywhere (even though I'm not sure it actually matters). If you call your database `TEST`, put `TEST` everywhere, not `Test` in some places and `TEST` in others.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem everything works now.